# Is a "Chain of Threads" a bad solution for this Java application?

Tags: java, multithreading, file-io

I'm running a program where I download large files, parse them and then write the data I have extracted from the file into another file.

The files take a long time to download and parse but the write task only takes a minute or so on average. My solution I threw together was to have three fixedthreadpools of three threads.

```
ExecutorService downloadExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
ExecutorService parseExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
ExecutorService writeExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
```

A thread in the download pool downloads the file, then submits a new thread to the parser threadpool, with the filename as a parameter. This is done within the thread itself. The download thread then gets to work downloading another file from a list of file URLs.

Once the parser thread has finished parsing the data I want from the file,it then submits a new thread containing the data to the write threadpool, where it is then written to a .csv file.

My question is if there is a more elegant solution to this. I have not really done much complex threading. Since I have a lot of files to download and parse, I do not want any of the threads being idle at any time. The idea again, is that since parsing a file can take a while, I might as well make seperate threads devoted to downloading those files first.

Answer (score 8):

Why not use only one Thread pool. Download, parse and save must wait anyway for each other so the best seperation of tasks would be to use one thread per file.

Comment: Well, as I mentioned, these files can be several GB's in size. The parsing can take well over 30 minutes to an hour to complete. My logic is that instead of waiting for the file to be parsed before downloading a new file, instead devote seperate threads that will continue download the files and when it has come down, submit that file to the threadpool. This will result in a queue of files awaiting parsing. It sounds more efficient to me.

Comment: Do the simplest thing first @GreenGodot. Your overall operation is limited by the slowest part anyway... do you really want hundreds of many GB files waiting on the disk?

Comment: If it helps any, I do delete the downloaded file using File.delete() when I have finished parsing the file. it does not solve the space problem completely but does that help?

Comment: Actually, could implementing a BlockingQueue on the parser's ExecutorService be a solution to the space problem? Since the submission of the thread is done through a download thread, if the queue is full wouldn't the download thread pause until it could submit the parser thread? Since the parser thread deletes the files when it is done, it would be a way of controlling disk space.

Comment: @GreenGodot There's no point creating threads if you don't have CPUs to run them on or data to feed into them. If download is fast but parse is slow, you can indeed queue the downloaded files up but you have to make sure you have the queue size under control.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a bad practice as many developers do similar sort of coding. But there are something you need to keep in mind.

Number One, You can't expect the performance to increase just because you have more threads. There are optimum number of threads based on the no of CPUs.

Number Two, You must make sure how exceptions are handled.

Number Three, You must make sure you can shutdown all the thread pools in an event where you need to stop the application.

Answer (score 2):

So your problem has two aspects:

1. Compute bound
2. IO bound

Reading and writing to the file is IO bound. Async IO is the best for IO bound tasks. Java has [AsynchronousFileChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousFileChannel.html) that allows you to read and write files without worrying about thread pools where continuation is achieved through completion handlers.
[Complete Example.](http://ruchirawageesha.blogspot.co.uk/2014/05/reading-file-using-java-asynchronous.html)

```
AsynchronousFileChannel ch = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(path);
    final ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
    ch.read(buf, 0, 0,
            new CompletionHandler() {
                public void completed(Integer result, Integer length){        
                    ..
                }
                
                public void failed(Throwable exc, Integer length) {
                    ..
                }
            }
    );
```

And you do the same for writes, you just write to the channel

```
ch.write(...
```

No for parsing the file, thats a compute bound task, and you should get your CPU cores hot for that, you can assign a thread pool equal to the number of cores you have.

```
 executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors())
```

Now what get to remember is: you need to test your code, and testing concurrent code is hard. If you can't proof its correctness, don't do it.